# Java Spark Dataframe fixed length file

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql

I want a fixed length file to be loaded depending on the given column name and length in separate file. I am able to load the data and append the new column. But, unable to retain the old column list. The column is getting overwritten. But, i want the complete list of columns. Below is the code, I have implemented:

```
samplefile.txt:

00120181120xyz12341
00220180203abc56792
00320181203pqr25483
00120181120xyz12341


schema.json:
{"Column":"id","length":"3","flag":"0"}
{"Column":"date","length":"8","flag":"0"}
{"Column":"name","length":"3","flag":"1"}
{"Column":"salary","length":"5","flag":"2"}


Current Output:

+-------------------+------+
|                _c0|salary|
+-------------------+------+
|00120181120xyz12341| 12341|
|00220180203abc56792| 56792|
|00320181203pqr25483| 25483|
|00120181120xyz12341| 12341|
+-------------------+------+

Expected Output

+-------------------+------++----+--------+---+
|                _c0|salary|name |date    |id | 
+-------------------+------++----+--------+---+
|00120181120xyz12341| 12341|xyz  |20181120|001|
|00220180203abc56792| 56792|abc  |20180203|002|
|00320181203pqr25483| 25483|pqr  |20181203|003|
|00120181120xyz12341| 12341|xyz  |20181120|001|
+-------------------+------+-----+--------+---+
```

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.spark.sql.Column;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;

public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Develop")
            .master("local").getOrCreate();

    Dataset<Row> ds = spark
            .read()
            .format("csv")
            .option("header", "false")
            .load("C://Users//path//samplefile.txt");
    ds.show();

    Dataset<Row> SchemaFile = spark
            .read()
            .format("csv")
            .option("header", "true")
            .load("C://Users//path//schema.txt");
    SchemaFile.show();
    List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
    int lens = 1;
    List<Row> it = SchemaFile.select("Column", "length").collectAsList();
    List<StructField> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Row fieldName : it) {
        System.out.println(fieldName.get(0));
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(fieldName.get(1).toString()));

        ds1 = ds.withColumn(
                fieldName.get(0).toString(),
                substrings(ds, "_c0", lens,
                        Integer.parseInt(fieldName.get(1).toString()),
                        fieldName.get(1).toString())); // selectExpr("substring("+"_c0"+","+lens+","+Integer.parseInt(fieldName.get(1).toString())+")");
        s.add(fieldName.get(0).toString());
        lens += Integer.parseInt((String) fieldName.get(1));
        System.out.println("Lengths:" + lens);
        ds1.show();
        StructField field = DataTypes.createStructField(
                fieldName.toString(), DataTypes.StringType, true);
        fields.add(field);
    }
    StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(fields);
    System.out.println(schema);
    for (String s1 : s) {
        System.out.println(s1);
    }


}

private static Column substrings(Dataset<Row> ds, String string, int lens,
        int i, String cols) {
    return ds.col("_c0").substr(lens, i);
}

}
```

Any kind of help and advice is appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

I know your question is quite old but maybe others come across this question as well and hope for an answer. I think you have just appended the wrong dataset and therefore dropped the columns after appending.

Possible solution:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

import java.util.List;

public class FlfReader {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("FixedLengthFileReader")
            .master("local[*]").getOrCreate();

    Dataset<Row> ds = spark
            .read()
            .format("csv")
            .option("header", "false")
            .load(FlfReader.class.getClassLoader().getResource("samplefile.txt").getPath());
    ds.show();

    Dataset<Row> SchemaFile = spark
            .read()
            .format("json")
            .option("header", "true")
            .load(FlfReader.class.getClassLoader().getResource("schema.json").getPath());
    SchemaFile.show();

    int lengths = 1;
    List<Row> schemaFields = SchemaFile.select("Column", "length").collectAsList();
    for (Row fieldName : schemaFields) {
        int fieldLength = Integer.parseInt(fieldName.get(1).toString());
        ds = ds.withColumn(
                fieldName.get(0).toString(),
                colSubstring(ds,
                        lengths,
                        fieldLength));
        lengths += fieldLength;
    }
    ds.show();
}

private static Column colSubstring(Dataset<Row> ds, int startPos, int length) {
        return ds.col("_c0").substr(startPos, length);
    }
}
```